# Angular page can’t be found on refresh

Tags: angular, iis, webapi, url-rewrite-module

I have an angular and a .net core wep api hosted on IIS on the same port.

Below is the folder structure.

Web API:
[image: Web API folder structure]

Angular App is in the **wwwroot** folder. (In the above image)
[image: Angular App]

The application works fine. However when the refresh the angular page, I get **page can’t be found** error.

Per internet research, this is due to missing URL rewrite rules, However I am not able to get this fixed.

I have installed URLRewrite module.
I have added below lines in web.config file in image#1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Angular-Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^webapi/" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

but nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ...well, basically idea is as following: you define your API controllers' paths to serve json (for you controllers' responses), for all other routes -> send index.html (with you angular app) ...

Comment: Did you use the ASP.NET Core SPA template for Angular to create this project? If not, you have to get back to that.

Comment: Please check if it redirects when you refresh the page?